# Frequency filtered image is black after performing inverse FFT

Tags: java, image, filter, fft, frequency

I'm writing a program that will calculate the FFT of an image, apply simple filters in the frequency domain, and then perform the inverse FFT to display the filtered image in the time domain.

I've done the following:

1. Create a NxN matrix such that N*N is a power of 2, and N is larger than the width and height of the original image.
2. Initialize the matrix to complex 0+0i.  Effectively padding the image with zeros.
3. Center the source image in the matrix, taking the log of each pixel value so they can eventually be displayed in a visible range in the frequency domain.  I handle each R/G/B color element in a separate matrix.
4. Convert the matrix to a 1D array and perform a 1D FFT on the data.  I'll later upgrade this to a 2D FFT.
5. Apply a filter to the frequency data.  In this case, I'm using a circle at the center of the frequency data.  This should act as a high-pass filter if the data outside the circle is excluded, or as a low-pass filter if the data inside the circle is excluded.
   In order to apply the filter, I'm replacing the complex number value for the rejected frequencies with 0+0i.  That should be the same as multiplying against a filter matrix of 1 for passing frequencies, and 0 for rejected frequencies.
6. Perform the inverse FFT on the filtered frequency data and construct the time-domain filtered image.

This all seems to work, with one exception:

When I use a frequency filter that **includes** the point at the center of the frequency domain, the inverse FFT succeeds and produces a image with only the high frequencies.

When I use a frequency filter that **excludes** the point at the center of the image, the resulting inverse FFT produces an entirely black image.

I'm unsure why the entire image result is black.  I expect it to contain all the low-frequency data.  Does the filter need to be symmetric?  Is there something special about the frequency point at the origin that I'm missing?

Comment: As a test, I used a filter that rejected a circle in the middle of the frequency domain, and then passed the middle few pixels.  The image is visible now.  There's something special that needs to be done regarding that middle pixel, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: It seems that removing the frequencies at the center of the frequency domain will remove the strongest signals in the image.  Those strong signals also provide a brightness boost to other pixels too.  If the other signals in the image are not amplified to compensate, the image will be too dark to recognize.  What is the appropriate method to adjust for the lost intensities?

Comment: You could normalize a floating point image by finding the min and max value, then (assuming intensity from [0...1]) : `pixel = (pixel-min) / (max-min)`

Comment: I'm not sure that will do what I need.  The intensity needs to be increased in the frequency domain before it is inverse FFT'ed.  The values in the frequency domain are complex numbers.  Since complex numbers are not ordered, I can't say which is greater than the other.  All I can use is the magnitude of the complex number.

Comment: Is the image zero all over? Or even `NaN`, `INF`? Could you provide code?

Comment: You might have your frequencies reversed.  Check to make sure the low frequencies, plus the required DC offset aren't in the middle circle.

Comment: (1) Did you check your data in the matrix? Are they all zero?   (2) Did you remove the DC component of your signal before applying FFT?  (3) Did you reverse the frequency when doing the FFT?

Comment: I'm essentially doing what is pictured here:  [Paul Bourke's FFT page](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/imagefilter/).  After I compute the FFT, I have to swap the frequency data across the origin to produce the cross image.  [Paul Bourke's swap across the origin image](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/imagefilter/sketch1.gif)  Are the pixels at the center of the image essentially the DC component then?  Once I'm done applying the low-pass filter, I swap the frequencies back across the origin and compute the inverse FFT.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about reversing the frequency when doing the FFT.  Can you explain a little about that?

Answer (score 1):

The "center" point of your transformed image represents the "DC Component" of the image, i.e. the avarage of all pixels in the "time" domain.

If you set this component to zero, you will shift all pixels down by this very amount. So your input range (RGB Vlues) of 0..255 will become -128 .. 128.

Either you shift the output back into some "visible" range, or you do not modify this DC component aka center pixel.